# Codeigniter: How to retrieve data inside foreach function in view

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter, I want to retrieve values from a different table inside the foreach loop, is it possible? Thanks

```
<?php
   foreach($sample as $key){

   }   
?>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Use join query to retrieve data.

Comment: What is the result of `$sample` and show both 2 table structures?

Answer (score 0):

Please explain/show your problem and give more code clarification
so we can answer you correctly
Yes you can show two tables data with join, Please see below link
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html
after fetching data from a model you need to pass data to the view via controller
please refer to this page
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html